# Javascript if doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I was making a simple program to reply
but the `if` statement doesn't work.
Here's my code :

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
var myBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
var value = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
var question = "Hi";

function message() {
  if ( value == question) {
   answer.innerHTML = "Hi, how can i help you?";
  } else {
   answer.innerHTML = "Hi ...";
  }
}
```

and here's the html part:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button id="myBtn" type="button" onclick="message()">Send!</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: I assure you `if`s work. Your data must be something other than what you expect. What debugging have you done?

Comment: It takes `value` only once from the input, at the start of the program, and then never updates even if you enter something into the input…

Comment: how i can update the value everytime the used type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your   **`var value = document.getElementById('myInput').value;`** inside the button click function

**DEMO**

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
var myBtn = document.getElementById('btn');

var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
var question = "Hi";

function message() {
   var value = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  console.log(value);
  console.log(question);
  if (value === question) {
   answer.innerHTML = "Hi, how can i help you?";
  } else {
   answer.innerHTML = "Hi ...";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button id="myBtn" type="button" onclick="message()">Send!</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're fetching the value before you have a chance to fill it in.

Instead, fetch it inside the `message` function.

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
var myBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
var question = "Hi";

function message() {
  var value = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  if (value == question) {
    answer.innerHTML = "Hi, how can i help you?";
  } else {
    answer.innerHTML = "Hi ...";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button id="myBtn" type="button" onclick="message()">Send!</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```